# replace values in dataframe using values from two lists

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I am cleaning some dataframes and want to replace a set of values with different values as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
dftmp=pd.DataFrame({
                  'a':['yes','true','false','no','na', 'NA', 'TRUE'],
                  'b':['yes','true','false','no','FALSE','ofcourse','yes we can'],
                  'c':['any','other','random','column','in', 'the', 'db']
                  })

       a        b       c
0    yes         yes     any
1   true        true   other
2  false       false  random
3     no          no  column
4     na       FALSE      in
5     NA    ofcourse     the
6   TRUE  yes we can      db
```

#replace with Y, N, NA. (actual combination of old and replacement values, and columns in which to replace is imported from another dataframe and will change over dataframes and time).

```
#next 3 variables populated from another database and can change. 
cols = ['a','b']
lstold = [['Yes, True'], ['No, False'], ['NA']]
lstnew = ['Y', 'N', 'NA']

for col in cols:
    dlsts = dict(zip(lstnew, lstold))
    for key, val in dlsts.items():
        try:
            valsold = val.split(', ')
        except:
            print('single item list. continue')
        for valold in valsold:
            dftmp[col] = dftmp[col].replace(f'(?i){valold}', key, regex=True)
```

I've almost got the desired result - the issue is in 6b, where it should should remain 'Yes we can' instead of 'Y we can':

```
   a         b       c
0  Y         Y     any
1  Y         Y   other
2  N         N  random
3  N         N  column
4  NA        N      in
5  NA  ofcourse     the
6  Y  Y we can      db
```

1. How do I stop the 'Yes' in 'Yes we can' from being replaced.
2. Can this be done without using 3 for loops? I fear it will take time a lot more time with my bigger datasets.

Thanks

Comment: But why did you replace false by 'Y' in your output? Did you intend to do that or it is a mistake? I think you need to replace only yes or true with 'Y', right?

Comment: that's incorrect.  shouldn't be happening. my loop is not working correctly, plus I realised the df.replace will not let me ignore case. reworking...

Comment: ok have fixed the loop and output it generates. Still have the problem with the ```yes``` in 6b being replaced with ```Y```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't reduce to less than three for loops. but thanks to response to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68414778/python-replace-case-insensitive-flag-doesnt-work) was able to stop replacement of substrings:

```
cols = ['a','b']
lstold = [['Yes, True'], ['No, False'], ['NA']]
lstnew = ['Y', 'N', 'NA']
for col in cols:
    dlsts = dict(zip(lstnew, lstold))
    for key, val in dlsts.items():
        try:
            valsold = val.split(', ')
        except:
            print('single item list. continue')
        for valold in valsold:
            df[col] = df[col].replace(rf'(?i)^{valold}$', key, regex=True)
```

if one doesn't need to ignore case or worry about replacing substrings, then one of the for loops can be dropped as follows:

```
cols = ['a','b']
lstold = [['Yes, True'], ['No, False'], ['NA']]
lstnew = ['Y', 'N', 'NA']
for col in cols:
    dlsts = dict(zip(lstnew, lstold))
    for key, val in dlsts.items():
        df[col] = df[col].str.replace(val, key, case=False, regex=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The sublists in your `lstold` aren't actually lists, they're a single string.  I changed that in the sample I'm showing to make each string an element of the list.  Assuming you can do that, perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
dftmp=pd.DataFrame({
                  'a':['yes','true','false','no','na', 'NA', 'TRUE'],
                  'b':['yes','true','false','no','FALSE','ofcourse','yes we can'],
                  'c':['any','other','random','column','in', 'the', 'db']
                  })


cols = ['a','b']
lstold = [['Yes', 'True'], ['No', 'False'], ['NA']]
lstnew = ['Y', 'N', 'NA']

m = {}
for c,l  in enumerate(lstold):
    for s in l:
        m[s.lower()] = lstnew[c]
        
for col in cols:
    dftmp[col].update(dftmp[col].str.lower().map(m))
```

Output

```
    a           b       c
0   Y           Y     any
1   Y           Y   other
2   N           N  random
3   N           N  column
4  NA           N      in
5  NA    ofcourse     the
6   Y  yes we can      db
```

Comment: in the last line what is ```rep```. Also after creating m, we're not using it anywhere. m looks funny: ```{'y': 'Y',
 'e': 'N',
 's': 'N',
 ',': 'N',
 ' ': 'N',
 't': 'Y',
 'r': 'Y',
 'u': 'Y',
 'n': 'NA',
 'o': 'N',
 'f': 'N',
 'a': 'NA',
 'l': 'N'}```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
lstold = [['Yes, True'], ['No, False'], ['NA']]
lstold  = [ a.lower() for x in lstold for a in x]
lstnew = ['Y','Y','N', 'N', 'NA']

for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = df[i].str.lower().replace(lstold,lstnew)
```

This is the output:

```
a               b       c
0   Y           Y     any
1   Y           Y   other
2   N           N  random
3   N           N  column
4  NA           N      in
5  NA    ofcourse     the
6   Y  yes we can      db
```

Comment: your solution requires me to hard code lstold and lstnew. It comes from an external database, structure the way I have shown. Plus the replacement text is an example. Other columns could have completely different sets of text for replacement.

Comment: You did not mention that in your question that you read old values from an external database, however, I updated the solution. But every column has a different replacement, that also not mentioned at all in your question and also algorithm.

Comment: You hard coded your algorithm in your code by ``` for valold in valsold: dftmp[col] = dftmp[col].replace(f'(?i){valold}', key, regex=True)``` my code solved your 2 mentioned problems.

Comment: You iterate through each column in your code without mentioned that is a problem.  my code solved your 2 mentioned problems.

Comment: Hamzawi, I mention twice in my question, once in the second snippet of code and also above the said code that the variables come from another dataframe. the problem I have with 6b isn't resolved.

Comment: I think with the last update, it is resolved, because you don't need to hard code anything. You just need to read the old vales as one list at the beginning.

Comment: Regarding 6b, yes is not replaced by 'Y' as you complained in your question because it is substring. How you said it is not resolved!